# How to remove new List padding that appeared on iOS14

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14

Ever since updating to iOS 14, I get additional padding (in red) in my `List` that I didn't see on iOS 13:

[image]

Is this a known issue of iOS 14 ? How can I fix this ?

```swift
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                List {
                   // Content goes here
                   // Mostly text and buttons
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("settings.title"), displayMode: .inline)
       }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the listStyle property? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/liststyle

Comment: @pawello2222 Yes it does! Thanks a lot, I didn't find the question when looking.